# How to convert XML to Json with binary data content

Tags: java, json, xml, converters

I try to convert from xml to json. It work well with normal text data content. When the data in a xml tag is a binary, we can not unmarshal the xml to java object. Can you help to share how we convert from xml to json for binary.

**Java Code**:

```
public <T> String xmlToJson(Class<T> clazz, String xmlString, boolean includeRoot) throws CustomException {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    String jsonString = "{}";

    try {

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, true);
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xmlString));
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", includeRoot);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX, "@");
        JAXBElement<T> addressFromXML = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, clazz); //ERROR at this line for binary data
        marshaller.marshal(addressFromXML, writer);
        jsonString = writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new CustomException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

**Here is the error**:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLBinaryDataHelper.initializeDataTypes(XMLBinaryDataHelper.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLBinaryDataHelper.<init>(XMLBinaryDataHelper.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLBinaryDataHelper.getXMLBinaryDataHelper(XMLBinaryDataHelper.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLInlineBinaryHandler.endElement(XMLInlineBinaryHandler.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.deferred.EndElementEvent.processEvent(EndElementEvent.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.deferred.DeferredContentHandler.executeEvents(DeferredContentHandler.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.deferred.BinaryMappingContentHandler.executeEvents(BinaryMappingContentHandler.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.deferred.BinaryMappingContentHandler.processSimpleElement(BinaryMappingContentHandler.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.deferred.DeferredContentHandler.endElement(DeferredContentHandler.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parseEvent(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader.parse(XMLStreamReaderReader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:460)
```

Comment: `But it fail for binary data content` - and where is error? It would help if you don't swallow exception in try/catch block ...

Comment: Hi @rkosegi, I have just update my question which include the stack trace. This is the first time I try to parse xml with binary content to object and from object to json.

Comment: <xs:element name="content" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation>binary content</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleType>
     <xs:restriction base="xs:base64Binary">
     </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xmlstring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart
```

You are missing java mail-api on your classpath.

If you're using maven, you should be able to fix that be adding floowing dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

More information about [Java Mail API](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/)

Comment: Thank rkosegi. It is working well. I still not understand why javax.mail will relate to unmarshal from xml to object. Can you help to explain?

Comment: After I add library <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @John java mail API is transitively required by [eclipselink](https://github.com/chenjiafan/eclipselink/blob/master/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/XMLBinaryDataHelper.java#L74)

Comment: Thank a lot. now I understood. For text data, it not call to third party libs. For binary data, it call to third party libs (javax.mail-api) to handle parser. Thank for your explanation.